# reserved keyword in dynamodb - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, amazon-dynamodb

Here is code:

```
queryExpression.keyConditionExpression = "#userId= :userId"
queryExpression.expressionAttributeNames = ["#userId":"userId", "#status":"status"]
queryExpression.expressionAttributeValues = [":userId":userID, ":status":"accept"]
queryExpression.projectionExpression = "status"
```

but I got the following error and I didnt know that status word is a reserved word in DynamoDB:

```
Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={message=Invalid ProjectionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: status, __type=com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException}
```

I have looked at the below link but I do not understand it and I can't find a Swift example. How do I accomplish this? 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.ReservedWords

I am new to DynamoDB things.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of all the reserved words in DynamoDB:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

so `ExpressionAttributeNames` and `expressionAttributeValues` are ways of aliasing to use `#fooattribute` and `:foovalue` even if `foo` were a reserved word within the above list.

So in your case, I believe your error is because the term `status` is reserved, you may try changing your last line to be :

`queryExpression.projectionExpression = "#status"`

That way you wouldn't be using the reserved word, it would read the alias instead. That alias would resolve to your actual attribute name which might as well be status.

Comment: Please see the updated post. Thanks for your response, MangoBoy.

Comment: Please make a separate post for new questions.